# How to change a string row value?

Tags: r

I would like to change some values of some particular rows. According to previous questions that seemed straight forward with `df[df$column=="value",]<-"new value"`
However I get error `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`
applying that:

Some data:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-13"), as.Date("2015-02-22"), by = "days")
b <- c("one","one","two","two","four","four","one","one","five","five")
c <- c(20,30,26,20,30,40,5,10,4,0)
d <- c(11,2233,12,2,22,13,23,23,100,1)
df <- data.frame(dates,b,c,d)
```

I just would like change all ones to seven:

```
df[df$b=="one",]<-"seven"
```

character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Maybe `df$b[df$b == "one"] <- "seven"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringr` library,

```
df$b <- str_replace_all(df$b, "one", "seven")
#        dates     b  c    d
#1  2015-02-13 seven 20   11
#2  2015-02-14 seven 30 2233
#3  2015-02-15   two 26   12
#4  2015-02-16   two 20    2
#5  2015-02-17  four 30   22
#6  2015-02-18  four 40   13
#7  2015-02-19 seven  5   23
#8  2015-02-20 seven 10   23
#9  2015-02-21  five  4  100
#10 2015-02-22  five  0   1
```

Comment: This is 5 or 6 times slower than the more traditional base R solution. Is there some benefit to doing it this way that I don't see?

Comment: @cory it works for factors as well as for characters

Comment: Using that approach just works for me. Using the R base gives me `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix` on my original data set. I dont know why and dont have much time to figure it out. So there is no need to down vote a correct answer.

Comment: To be clear... I didn't downvote it. I just think unnecessary to use a third party library to do something like this, especially when it's slower. The fact that it takes a factor and changes it to a character isn't a benefit to me. That's downright dangerous if you expect the result to still be a factor.

Comment: Nevertheless, It is another way of doing what the OP wanted. Almost all of the question regarding `R` have different solutions utilizing different packages

Comment: Agreed. I don't know if R has a notion like Python does of being "Pythonic". There's just something a little cringey about this way of doing it. Whatever floats your boat, I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Two things... `stringsAsFactors` and the assignment.

I've pretty much gotten used to using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` any time I use `read.csv` or `read.*` in general and `data.frame`. It's burned me so many times, and sometimes it's completely silent with no warnings or errors when it does burn you.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-13"), as.Date("2015-02-22"), by = "days")
b <- c("one","one","two","two","four","four","one","one","five","five")
c <- c(20,30,26,20,30,40,5,10,4,0)
d <- c(11,2233,12,2,22,13,23,23,100,1)
df <- data.frame(dates,b,c,d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$b[df$b=="one"]<-"seven"
```